# How to apply changes only to new fields after "add new" event?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, input, jquery-selectors

I have a piece of code which automatically fills new fields with a certain number. However, this automatically also updates the values before edited by a user. I need to adjust this code so that only newly added lines include the desired prefilled number without editing any others.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  copyValueToRepeat();

  var sourceField = document.getElementById( 'field_jimvh' );
  sourceField.addEventListener( "change", function(event) {
  copyValueToRepeat();
  });

});

jQuery(document).on('frmAfterAddRow', copyValueToRepeat );

function copyValueToRepeat(){
  var sourceField = document.getElementById( 'field_jimvh' );
  var repeatFields = document.querySelectorAll( '.frm_field_216_container input');

 for ( var i = 0, len=repeatFields.length; i<len; i++ ) {
        repeatFields[i].value = sourceField.value;
    }   

}
```

I believe the problem is in the for loop at the end but I don't know how to adjust it exactly. I assume this problem will be trivial but my programming skills are basic.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This line "var repeatFields = document.querySelectorAll( '.frm_field_216_container input');" selects all the fields that have the mentioned class which apparently include all your fields including the old ones. You can try adding another class to the new field and select using it if that's possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible as I am working with a Wordpress plugin. The x value in name increases by 1 every time (_item_meta[201][x][216]_), though. Could I work around that way? Applying the script only to "higher" numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure how can it be done in a robust way. Maybe someone with a better knowledge in Wordpress can help. You should add these details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `document.querySelectorAll( '.frm_field_216_container input')` selects all the fields. 
You might want to add an extra css class in the new fields like 'new_input_field' and then modify your query selector to: `document.querySelectorAll( '.frm_field_216_container .new_input_field')`